# event.type undefined in firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox

I have the following function:

```
format : function(element,p){
 //function body
 if(event.type == 'focus'){
   //execute this condition only on focus event 
 }
}
```

that is being called on the focus event and on page load. element is the input element's value and p is an optional arguement, I want to execute the if only on the focus on the input element. If I simply apply event.type == 'focus', it works for IE and chrome, but for firefox it says event is not defined.

Does anyone have a workaround for this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You've not defined an `event` parameter for the function, and FF doesn't have a global `window.event` object.

Comment: Firefox doesn't provide the current event object as global variable. You have to pass it to the function from the event handler.

Answer (score 0):

```
var myObj = {
    format: function (event) {
        // passing in the event object should give you everything you need:
        // event.type (the event's type)
        // event.target (the element which the event was fired on)
        // event.which (in the case of keyboard events, this is the key that was pressed)
        // see mdn dox @ https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event
        if (event.type === 'focus') {
            // execute focus code
        }
    }
};
```